# JSON array count in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the array below:

```
[{"__metadata":{"id":"bba6f593-167d-4f14-85cf-3b69288f5434","etag":"\"1\"","type":"SP.Data.PollLogListItem"},"PollId":1,"Answer":"Option3"},{"__metadata":{"id":"925dceaf-250f-43c1-be73-9972b0a34750","etag":"\"2\"","type":"SP.Data.PollLogListItem"},"PollId":1,"Answer":"Option4"},{"__metadata":{"id":"85c73abb-a565-4e2c-b74c-1883c15e2eb6","etag":"\"1\"","type":"SP.Data.PollLogListItem"},"PollId":1,"Answer":"Option3"}]
```

How can I get a count by group as below:

```
[
  {"Answer":"Option3","Count":2},
  {"Answer":"Option4","Count":1}
]
```

I my previous array there is no Count key. I tried below but it is giving an error. Can somebody help me?

```js
const data = [{"__metadata":{"id":"bba6f593-167d-4f14-85cf-3b69288f5434","etag":"\"1\"","type":"SP.Data.PollLogListItem"},"PollId":1,"Answer":"Option3"},{"__metadata":{"id":"925dceaf-250f-43c1-be73-9972b0a34750","etag":"\"2\"","type":"SP.Data.PollLogListItem"},"PollId":1,"Answer":"Option4"},{"__metadata":{"id":"85c73abb-a565-4e2c-b74c-1883c15e2eb6","etag":"\"1\"","type":"SP.Data.PollLogListItem"},"PollId":1,"Answer":"Option3"}];

function getCount(pollLog) {
  counts = pollLog.reduce(function(r, o) {
    if (r[o.Answer]) { //!(o.Answer in r)
      r.push(r[o.Answer] = o);
      r[o.Answer].Count = 1;
    } else {
      r[o.Answer].Count += 1;
    }
  }, {})
  return counts;
}

getCount(data)
```

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: i already created object

Comment: @Milind in that case it has nothing to do with JSON, instead you're dealing with JavaScript arrays and objects. The question also appears to have nothing to do with jQuery. Edited the tags for you.

Comment: what is the error in your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a `Map` for this (or an object created with `Object.create(null)` if you have to support obsolete environments without a polyfill for `Map`):

```
const answers = new Map();
for (const {Answer: answer} of data) {
  if (answers.has(answer)) {
    answers.set(answer, answers.get(answer) + 1);
  } else {
    answers.set(answer, 1);
  }
}
```

Then if you really want that array of objects instead of the `Map`:

```
const array = [...answers.entries()].map(([Answer, Count]) => ({Answer, Count}));
```

Live Example:

```js
const data = [{"__metadata":{"id":"bba6f593-167d-4f14-85cf-3b69288f5434","etag":"\"1\"","type":"SP.Data.PollLogListItem"},"PollId":1,"Answer":"Option3"},{"__metadata":{"id":"925dceaf-250f-43c1-be73-9972b0a34750","etag":"\"2\"","type":"SP.Data.PollLogListItem"},"PollId":1,"Answer":"Option4"},{"__metadata":{"id":"85c73abb-a565-4e2c-b74c-1883c15e2eb6","etag":"\"1\"","type":"SP.Data.PollLogListItem"},"PollId":1,"Answer":"Option3"}];

const answers = new Map();
for (const {Answer: answer} of data) {
  if (answers.has(answer)) {
    answers.set(answer, answers.get(answer) + 1);
  } else {
    answers.set(answer, 1);
  }
}

console.log(...answers);

// If you want the array of objects:
const array = [...answers.entries()].map(([Answer, Count]) => ({Answer, Count}));

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for ignorant question where I will pass my original array

Comment: @Milind: that's `data`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `reduce()` logic isn't right and you aren't  returning the accumulator.

The accumulator is an object so you can't `push()` to it. When `r[o.Answer]` doesn't exist you want to create a new object for that property value.

Finally instead of returning the reduce object , return it's values as array

```js
function getCount(pollLog) {
  var counts = pollLog.reduce(function(r, o) {
    if (!r[o.Answer]) { 
      r[o.Answer] = {Answer: o.Answer, Count:0}     
    }
    r[o.Answer].Count ++;
    // must return the accumulator
    return r;
  }, {})
  return Object.values(counts);
}

console.log(getCount(data))
```

```html
<script>
  var data = [{"__metadata":{"id":"bba6f593-167d-4f14-85cf-3b69288f5434","etag":"\"1\"","type":"SP.Data.PollLogListItem"},"PollId":1,"Answer":"Option3"},{"__metadata":{"id":"925dceaf-250f-43c1-be73-9972b0a34750","etag":"\"2\"","type":"SP.Data.PollLogListItem"},"PollId":1,"Answer":"Option4"},{"__metadata":{"id":"85c73abb-a565-4e2c-b74c-1883c15e2eb6","etag":"\"1\"","type":"SP.Data.PollLogListItem"},"PollId":1,"Answer":"Option3"}]
</script>
```

Comment: Stacksnippets don't seem to be working today. Here's a working version https://jsfiddle.net/v1g635hj/

Answer (score 1):

Here is an ES2017+ way to get the counts for all your array items in O(N):

```
const arr = [...yourArray];
const counts = {};

arr.forEach((el) => {
  const answer = el['Answer']
  counts[answer] = counts[answer] ? (counts[answer] += 1) : 1;
});

const countsSorted = Object.entries(counts).sort(([_, a], [__, b]) => a - b);
const result = countsSorted.map([a, c] => ({Answer: a, Count: c}))
```

console.log(result) for your example array:

```
[ { Answer: 'Option3', Count: 2 }, { Answer: 'Option4', Count: 1 } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your reduce callback function is incorrect, if you need to use this code in browser or in some es5 environment, then here is one of solutions.

```js
var data = [{"__metadata":{"id":"bba6f593-167d-4f14-85cf-3b69288f5434","etag":"\"1\"","type":"SP.Data.PollLogListItem"},"PollId":1,"Answer":"Option3"},{"__metadata":{"id":"925dceaf-250f-43c1-be73-9972b0a34750","etag":"\"2\"","type":"SP.Data.PollLogListItem"},"PollId":1,"Answer":"Option4"},{"__metadata":{"id":"85c73abb-a565-4e2c-b74c-1883c15e2eb6","etag":"\"1\"","type":"SP.Data.PollLogListItem"},"PollId":1,"Answer":"Option3"}];

function getCount(pollLog){
  const answersCount = pollLog.reduce(function (r, o) {
    var answer = o["Answer"];
    
    if (!r[answer]) {
      r[answer] = 1
    } else {
      r[answer] += 1;
    }
    
    return r;
  }, {});
  
  return Object.keys(answersCount).map(function(key) {
    return {"Answer":key, "Count": answersCount[key]+""}
  });
}

alert(JSON.stringify(getCount(data)));
```

Or here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hgen4Lzp/

If you can use ecma2017 (no need for IE support), go with the solution provided by @charlietfl